# Remove Save Draft & Preview Buttions.. and also Statius: Draft & Visibility: Public

Tags: buttons, draft, customization, post-status

I want to remove the entire section that says Save Draft, Preview and Status: Draft and Visibility: Public.

I want to not show it. Its ok if it is still fuctional.

Attached is the part I do not want to display.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Here is the area I want to not display:

http://kind.s3.amazonaws.com/removethissection.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide them using CSS. Add this to the theme's functions.php file, or add a plug-in header to the top of the file and zip it up to use as a plug-in:

```
<?php
  add_action('admin_print_styles', 'remove_this_stuff');
  function remove_this_stuff() {
  ?>
<style>
  #misc-publishing-actions, #minor-publishing-actions {
  display:none;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I can't get it to work.. Also the contact form on your site doesn't work because I tried to email you. Please write back.

Comment: I fixed the contact form, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution doesn't work (returns error 500), but this one does:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'leave_only_publish_button');

function leave_only_publish_button() {
    if( !current_user_can('activate_plugins') ) { //doesn't affect users who can activate plugins, remove if needed
        echo '<style>
            #misc-publishing-actions, #minor-publishing-actions {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: The code [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41544/26350) seems to be valid PHP, but one has to be careful when doing copy/paste into `functions.php` regarding the opening `<?php` and closing `?>`.

Comment: The problem isn't in the opening and closing PHP tags for the code you linked.